# Can't fetch titles from some box-like containers

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in `python` in association with `selenium` to click on some dots available on a map in a web page. When a dot is clicked, a small box containing relevant information pops up.

***[Link to that site](https://www.arcgis.com/apps/Embed/index.html?webmap=4712740e6d6747d18cffc6a5fa5988f8&extent=-141.1354,10.7295,-49.7292,57.6712&zoom=true&scale=true&search=true&searchextent=true&details=true&legend=true&active_panel=details&basemap_gallery=true&disable_scroll=true&theme=light)***

I would like to parse the title of each box. When I execute my script, it throws an error while clicking on a dot. How can I make a go successfully?

This is the script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = "replace with above link"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#mapDiv_zoom_slider .esriSimpleSliderIncrementButton"))).click()
for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#NWQMC_VM_directory_June2016_3915_0_layer circle"))):
    item.click()
```

Error I'm having:

```
line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <circle fill="rgb(237, 81, 81)" fill-opacity="1" stroke="rgb(153, 153, 153)" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="4" cx="720" cy="430" r="4" transform="matrix(1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000,1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000)" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-dasharray="none" dojoGfxStrokeStyle="solid"></circle> is not clickable at point (720, 430). Other element would receive the click: <circle fill="rgb(20, 158, 206)" fill-opacity="1" stroke="rgb(153, 153, 153)" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="4" cx="720" cy="430" r="4" transform="matrix(1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000,1.00000000,0.00000000,0.00000000)" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-dasharray="none" dojoGfxStrokeStyle="solid"></circle>
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86)
```

This is how a box gets popped up:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Andrei Suvorkov was really close (+1)

Try below code to get required output:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
driver.maximize_window()

items = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='circle']")))
for item in items:
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(item).click(item).perform()
    popup = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "contentPane")))
    print(popup.text)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'close')]"))).click()
```

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know about this `WebDriverWait(popup, 5)`. I thought it is only for driver

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov , oh... Actually that code was redundant)) But yeah, if you want to use relative XPath in ExplicitWait, you should do it like `element =  wait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//node")))` , `another_element =  wait(element, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//another_node")))`

Comment: I didn't shut down my pc only because I noticed that you are online @sir Andersson. As long as you are available, there is hardly any chance to failure. Thanks a lot. it did the trick wonderfully.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your particular question you cannot interact with `svg` elements like usual. For that you have to use `xPath` like I have provided in the example. Also you cannot click on these elements like usual, but you can use `ActionChains`.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#mapDiv_zoom_slider .esriSimpleSliderIncrementButton"))).click()
time.sleep(3)
items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='circle']")
i = 0
for item in items:
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(item).click(item).perform()
    except Exception:
        print("Can't click")
```

This code works and every element will be clicked until the map will be zoomed in. At one of the elements the map zooms in and it doesn't work after that. Why? I didn't found out yet, but you can find it from yourself or ask another question and we will try to help you.

***Note:*** you have to add some imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
```

***EDIT:*** I have found the problem, you have to close every popup after click and then it works. The working code is below:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#mapDiv_zoom_slider .esriSimpleSliderIncrementButton"))).click()
time.sleep(3) # wait until all elements will be ready
items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='circle']")
for item in items:
    time.sleep(0.5) # small pause before each iteration
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(item).click(item).perform()
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@title = 'Close']"))).click()
```

I didn't find a way to avoid `time.sleep()`, probably in this particular case it is not possible.

Comment: This is a portion of error I get when I try with your suggested script; `line 397, in _find_element
    return driver.find_element(*by)
TypeError: find_element() argument after * must be an iterable, not WebElement`

Comment: I have edited my answer, please have a look and try the code snippet

Comment: The problem with particular element is solved, I have added the code snippet in the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. It works partially (not solved yet). After 5/7 clicks, It throws `timeout exception` error pointing at the last line..

Comment: I have just tested one more time on my local machine - works perfect. Try to increase `time.sleep(0.5)` to `time.sleep(1)`. I think the script is too quick

Comment: I did that as well but encountered the same issue. Don't you think `time.sleep(4)` is enough? After few clicks, it suddenly clicks elsewhere and a new tab opens up and as aresult it throws `timeout exception` error again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176443/discussion-between-andrei-suvorkov-and-topto).