# Can't click on some dots to scrape information

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, internet-explorer-11

I've written a script in vba in combination with IE to click on some dots available on a map in a web page. When a dot is clicked, a small box containing relevant information pops up.

[Link to that website](https://www.arcgis.com/apps/Embed/index.html?webmap=4712740e6d6747d18cffc6a5fa5988f8&extent=-141.1354,10.7295,-49.7292,57.6712&zoom=true&scale=true&search=true&searchextent=true&details=true&legend=true&active_panel=details&basemap_gallery=true&disable_scroll=true&theme=light)

I would like to parse the content of each box. The content of that box can be found using class name `contentPane`. However, the main concern here is to generate each box by clicking on those dots. When a box shows up, it looks how you can see in the below image.

This is the script I've tried so far:

```
Sub HitDotOnAMap()
    Const Url As String = "https://www.arcgis.com/apps/Embed/index.html?webmap=4712740e6d6747d18cffc6a5fa5988f8&extent=-141.1354,10.7295,-49.7292,57.6712&zoom=true&scale=true&search=true&searchextent=true&details=true&legend=true&active_panel=details&basemap_gallery=true&disable_scroll=true&theme=light"
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, HTML As HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object, I&
    
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate Url
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set HTML = .document
    End With
    
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:0:07")  ''the following line zooms in the slider
    HTML.querySelector("#mapDiv_zoom_slider .esriSimpleSliderIncrementButton").Click
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:0:04")
    
    With HTML.querySelectorAll("[id^='NWQMC_VM_directory_'] circle")
        For I = 0 To .Length - 1
            .item(I).Focus
            .item(I).Click
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:0:03")
            Set post = HTML.querySelector(".contentPane")
            Debug.Print post.innerText
            HTML.querySelector("[class$='close']").Click
        Next I
    End With
End Sub
```

> when I execute the above script, it looks like it is running smoothly but nothing happens (I meant, no clicking) and it doesn't throw any error either. Finally it quits the browser gracefully.

This is how a box with information looks like when a dot gets clicked.

[image]

> Although I've used hardcoded delay within my script, they can be fixed later as soon as the macro starts working.

***Question: How can I click each of the dots on that map and collect the relevant information from the popped-up box? I only expect to have any solution using `Internet Explorer`***

> The data are not the main concern here. I would like to know how IE work in such cases so that I can deal with them in future cases. Any solution other than IE is not I'm looking for.

Comment: To be solved only with IE?

Comment: Always a pleasure to find you in the loop @QHarr. Yes, only with `IE` because I've already solved using `selenium`. Thanks.

Comment: It will not work this way I am afraid. The `circle` is of type `SVGCircleElement` which doesn't have any `click-event`. The click is handled in function `_mouseClick:function(b){...` and processed then. The parameter `b` is of type `[object PointerEvent]`. Maybe you could better try to look at the documentation [here](https://developers.arcgis.com).

Comment: Check out [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51448664/cant-fetch-titles-from-some-box-like-containers) I got using python in combination with selenium where click event worked just perfect. The language is different, though!

Comment: @dee - Actually, Click does exist on IE's SVGCircleElement (because it derives ultimately from Element/IHTMLElement), but it does nothing. Topto, have you tested the selenium stuff with IE11?

Comment: If you want help, answer the questions people ask

Comment: Dreadfully sorry @Simon Mourier for my belated response. Nope, I didn't try IE within selenium. In fact I don't know how to use IE within selenium. I'm accustomed to using chrome within selenium.

Comment: @Topto You simply change the driver to IEDriver rather than ChromeDriver.    Dim driver As New IEDriver. No biggie.

Answer (score 13):

No need to click on each dots. Json file has all the details and you can extract as per your requirement.

---

**Installation of JsonConverter**

1. Download the [latest release](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/releases)
2. Import JsonConverter.bas into your project (Open VBA Editor, Alt + F11; File > Import File)
   Add Dictionary reference/class
3. For Windows-only, include a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"
4. For Windows and Mac, include VBA-Dictionary

---

**References to be added**

[image]

---

**Download the sample file** [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11ge3siSQMYQhfbmbr5BvRIUmfIiysNRR/view?usp=sharing).

---

**Code:**

```
Sub HitDotOnAMap()

    Const Url As String = "https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/4712740e6d6747d18cffc6a5fa5988f8/data?f=json"
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, HTML As HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object, I&
    Dim data As String, colObj As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate Url
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        data = .document.body.innerHTML
        data = Replace(Replace(data, "<pre>", ""), "</pre>", "")
    End With

    Dim JSON As Object
    Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(data)
    Set colObj = JSON("operationalLayers")(1)("featureCollection")("layers")(1)("featureSet")

    For Each Item In colObj("features")


         For j = 1 To Item("attributes").Count - 1
                Debug.Print Item("attributes").Keys()(j), Item("attributes").Items()(j)

         Next
    Next
End Sub
```

**Output**

[image]